# Getting a list in R to a data frame

Tags: r

How do I bind lists into a dataframe but not attaching them row-wise as does this one that I use now:  dataframe_trees <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, trees) but rather adding them into columns like: `[1][2][3]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `rbind.data.frame` in your `do.call` to `cbind.data.frame`. 
If your dataframes in the list have the same number of rows then you can also use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package. This a more efficient version of the same `do.call`

```r
df <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, trees)
```

Or equivalently:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(trees)
```